# Is there a way that one function can use the variables of another function without any argument passing in C++?

Tags: c++, function

If I have 2 functions like follows:

```
template <typename T>
void A(int n)
{
   T a[n];   // need to use this array of variables in function B without any passing
  // assignment of values to a[n] variables and rest of code for function A
}

void B()
{
   // need to use a[n] array here without passing
}
```

Can the static array `T a[n]` be used in function `B` somehow without passing the arguments to `B` explicitly?
Is it called `function forwarding` or `perfect forwarding` in C++?

I'm aware that creating attempting to create a static array out of a variable `int` isn't standard C++ and some compilers support it. My main question is can the arguments be used in `B` without passing?

Comment: T a[n] is not a static array, a[n] (though some compilers support it) is not valid C++. function forwarding and perfect forwarding are totally different concepts. If you want functions to share data then put them in the same class... Looks like you're trying to run before you can walk. Get a C++ book and take it step by step

Comment: No, that's not valid c++ syntax. You'll need a template constant for `n`.

Comment: I'm aware that `T a[n]` isn't standard C++ and some compilers support it. Is there a way to make it standard?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How can I create that template constant? Just use `const_cast`?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma `template <typename T, int n>` just as done with `std::array<T,Size>`, which you should prefer anyways.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Isn't `int n` in `template <typename T, int n>` treated like a variable?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma No, it's a template parameter, which needs to be evaluatable at compile time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Makes sense. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: *"Is it called `function forwarding` or `perfect forwarding` in C++?"* Neither. It is called "Bad Design" in C++.

Comment: A() could set a global variable (or if you change both functions to be class-methods of the same class, a member-variable), and then B() could read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Functions have a scope, names of automatic variables are inaccessible outside of that scope, and other functions are outside of that scope.

> Is it called function forwarding or perfect forwarding in C++?

No, what you're asking about is not related to forwarding. Forwarding is passing of arguments which is the opposite of what you are asking for.